# Проблема с ЧПУ на сайте

Tags: php, .htaccess, чпу

Пытаюсь сделать ЧПУ на сайте, в файлике `.htaccess` прописал следующее:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z])/$ ?view=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Проблема в следующем: в адресной строке при нажатии на ссылку, к примеру я так прописал, `about/`, переходит на страничку и все ок. Но, если я, после этого нажимаю на любую другую ссылку, к примеру, `contacts/` (на сайте всего 5 страничек: главная, контакты, о компании, каталог, фотоальбом) то в итоге, в адресной строке имею: `about/contacts/` а не `contacts/`. То есть получается, что к первому адресу прилипает второй и осуществляется переход на несуществующую страничку. Как этого избежать? П

Comment: Используйте обсалбтные пути для ссылок например '/contacts'  а не 'contacts'

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам - Ваш совет помог :) я вот только учусь всему этому, ломал голову сутки :) спс спс спс

Comment: По началу и не такое бывает незашто в общем

Comment: @Naumov Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.